# Why does this map block contain an apparently useless +?

Tags: perl, dictionary

While browsing the source code I saw the following lines:

```
my @files_to_keep = qw (file1 file2);
my %keep = map { + $_ => 1 } @files_to_keep;
```

What does the `+` do in this code snippet? I used `Data::Dumper` to see whether taking out the plus sign does anything, but the results were the same:

```
  $ perl cleanme.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'file1' => 1,
          'file2' => 1
        };
```

Comment: Check at the end of the docs too for some more info: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is used to prevent a parsing problem. The plus symbol forces the interpreter to behave like a normal block and not an expression.

The fear is that perhaps you are trying to create a hashreference using the other (expression) formulation of `map` like so.

```
@array_of_hashrefs = map {  "\L$_" => 1  }, @array
```

Notice the comma. Then if the parser guesses that you are doing this given the statement in the OP there will a syntax error for missing the comma! To see the difference try quoting `"$_"`. For whatever reason, the parser takes this as enough to trigger the expression behavior.

Yes its an oddity. Therefore many extra-paranoid Perl programmers toss in the extra plus sign more often than needed (me included).

Here are the examples from the [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) documentation.

```
%hash = map {  "\L$_" => 1  } @array  # perl guesses EXPR.  wrong
%hash = map { +"\L$_" => 1  } @array  # perl guesses BLOCK. right
%hash = map { ("\L$_" => 1) } @array  # this also works
%hash = map {  lc($_) => 1  } @array  # as does this.
%hash = map +( lc($_) => 1 ), @array  # this is EXPR and works!
%hash = map  ( lc($_), 1 ),   @array  # evaluates to (1, @array)
```

For a fun read (stylistically) and a case where the parser gets it wrong read this: http://blogs.perl.org/users/tom_wyant/2012/01/the-case-of-the-overloaded-curlys.html

Comment: NB: Tried other operators, but they get prefixed to the `key`. Only `+` works accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I get the map BLOCK LIST syntax such as `my @squares = map { $_ * $_ } @numbers;`, but when do you ever use map EXPR LIST? (or maybe other way around. I am still confused between the term BLOCK and EXPR)

Comment: Remember that a block is like a mini subroutine which can do anything that Perl might do in a sub. The expression form is more for tiny transforms that don't really need a whole block, something like `my @out = map "hi $_", @inputs;`. Some people probably prefer this simpler form, but I always use the block form myself.

Comment: @Joel Berger, A block is not like a mini subroutine. If you say that because map calls it repeatedly, then you're saying multiplicatino is also mini subroutine (because you can do `map $_*2, @L`). *The first argument of map* is like a mini subroutine. Without args. And from which you can't `return`. Ok, so that's not like a mini subroutine either. What are you talking about?!

Comment: @Ably, Whenever you want to. `map { $_*$_ } @numbers` can be written as `map($_*$_, @numbers)` or just `map $_*$_, @numbers`.

Comment: @Alby, A block is an series of statements inside of curly braces. An expression is a piece of code that can be used as an operand to operator.

Comment: @ikegami, "A block is an series of statements inside of curly braces" thats what I was going for. sorry I didn't phrase it in a useful way

Answer (score 8):

The unary-plus operator simply returns its operand unchanged. Adding one doesn't even change the context.

In the example you gave, it is completely useless. But there are situations where it is useful to make the next token something that's undeniably an operator.

---

For example, `map` has two syntaxes.

```
map EXPR, LIST
```

and

```
map BLOCK LIST
```

A block starts with `{`, but so can an expression. For example, `{ }` can be a block or a hash constructor.

So how can `map` tell the difference? It guesses. Which means it's sometimes wrong.

One occasion where is guesses wrong is the following:

```
map { $_ => 1 }, @list
```

You can prod it in to guessing correctly using `+` or `;`.

```
map {; ...     # BLOCK
map +{ ...     # EXPR
```

So in this case, you could use

```
map +{ foo => $_ }, @list
```

Note that you could also use the following:

```
map({ foo => $_ }, @list)
```

---

Another example is when you omit the parens around arguments, and the first argument expression starts with a paren.

```
print ($x+$y)*2;    # Same as: 2 * print($x+$y)
```

It can be fixed using

```
print +($x+$y)*2;
```

But why pile on a hack just to avoid parens? I prefer

```
print(($x+$y)*2);
```