# perl: grep on constant array

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I want to find if the value in $myVar is present in the constant MY_ARRAY. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
use constant {
  MY_ARRAY => ['E1', 'E2']
};
.
.
my $myVar = 'E2';
if ( grep( /^$myVar$/, MY_ARRAY ) ) {
...
}
```

Comment: What about this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dereference it with `@{}`

```
if ( grep( $_ eq $myVar, @{+MY_ARRAY} ) ) {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Can you point me to a reference that explains why + is required here?

Comment: It's for disambiguation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683158/why-cant-i-have-a-literal-list-slice-right-after-a-print-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617546/whats-the-history-of-the-in-front-of-a-hashref-that-disambiguates-from-a-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277284/why-does-this-map-block-contain-an-apparently-useless